# Type assertions with interface embedding in Go

Tags: go, interface, casting, type-assertion

- I have an interface and it is embedded into multiple structs that
  form a decorator pattern.
- Now I have added code to typecast `Validator` and `APIService` to the API interface. So that if I add and a function to the interface then I should be able to add it at `Validator` and `APIService`.

*But this code seems to compile.*
***I should have got a compiler error as I have not implemented `Get` on `Validator`***
*If I remove `Get` from `APIService` I get an error which says I cant typecast to `*APIService` to `API` as get is not implemented.*

```
package main

import "fmt"

type API interface {
  Get()
}
var _ API = (*Validator)(nil)
var _ API = (*APIService)(nil)

type APIService struct {
  id string
}

type Validator struct {
  API
}

type APIRouter struct {
  API
}

func(a *APIService) Get(){
  fmt.Println("Calling Get api on APIService")
}

func NewAPIRouter() *APIRouter{
  return &APIRouter{
    API: &Validator{
      API: &APIService{
      },
    },
  }
}
func main() {
  var api API = NewAPIRouter()
  api.Get()
}
```

If I compile the above code:

```sh
./main
Calling Get api on APIService
```

But if I comment `Get` function on `APIService` i get the below error which is valid:

```sh
go build
# main
./main.go:9:5: cannot use (*APIService)(nil) (type *APIService) as type API in assignment:
    *APIService does not implement API (missing Get method)
```

***I should have got a compiler error before as well as I have not implemented `Get` on `Validator`***
*If I remove `Get` from `APIService` I get an error which says I cant typecast to `*APIService` to `API` as get is not implemented.*

Comment: You've chosen to define the method by embedding the interface, which means it will fulfill the type assertion. Calling a method on a nil interface is a runtime error, not a compile time error.

Comment: the code after the import line. `var _ API = (*Validator)(nil)` this line should fail right?

Comment: @DineshGowda No, the type `Validator` satisfies the interface using the `Get` method promoted from the field `API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `APIService` is a struct with a method `Get`, so it implements `API` interface.

The type `Validator` is a struct with an embedded interface `API`. This means, a `Validator` instance has an embedded member that implements the `API` interface, and since it is embedded, `Validator` also implemented the `API` interface. However, note that you have to initialize `Validator.API` to an implementation first. Something like this should work:

```
v:=Validator{API:&APIService{}}
```

With this, `v.Get()` will call the embedded `APIService.Get`.

Comment: the code after import line.  `var _ API = (*Validator)(nil)` this line should fail right?

Comment: No. `*Validator` impements `API` interface because of the promoted method.